# `nm` output symbols not referenced by `LC_SYMTAB`

Tags: c, macos, dyld, mach-o, nm

## Why ?

I am trying to reproduce the behavior of `nm`.

## Problem

The command `nm /usr/libexec/sharingd` output some stranges symbols like :

```
[..]
00000001001d7570 t -[_TtC8sharingd19SDAirDropHandlerIPA canHandleTransfer]
00000001001d8070 t -[_TtC8sharingd19SDAirDropHandlerIPA initWithTransfer:bundleIdentifier:]
00000001001d7ed0 t -[_TtC8sharingd19SDAirDropHandlerIPA singleItemActionTitle]
00000001001d75f0 t -[_TtC8sharingd19SDAirDropHandlerIPA suitableContentsDescription]
00000001001d7580 t -[_TtC8sharingd19SDAirDropHandlerIPA transferTypes]
00000001001e45a0 t -[_TtC8sharingd27SDAirDropContactHashManager .cxx_destruct]
00000001001daf60 t -[_TtC8sharingd27SDAirDropContactHashManager acquireTokenForIdentifier:]
00000001001dcf70 t -[_TtC8sharingd27SDAirDropContactHashManager init]
00000001001be700 t <redacted function 7904>
00000001001beb50 t <redacted function 7905>
00000001001bebf0 t <redacted function 7906>
00000001001bf050 t <redacted function 7907>
00000001001bf100 t <redacted function 7908>
00000001001bf3a0 t <redacted function 7909>
00000001001bf490 t <redacted function 7910>
00000001001bf4d0 t <redacted function 7911>
00000001001bf540 t <redacted function 7912>
00000001001bf580 t <redacted function 7913>
00000001001bf590 t <redacted function 7914>
00000001001bf5b0 t <redacted function 7915>
00000001001bf5d0 t <redacted function 7916>
00000001001bf5e0 t <redacted function 7917>
00000001001bf5f0 t <redacted function 7918>
[..]
```

My version of `nm` doesn't output these symbols.

Where do they come from ?

## Ascertainments

### 1.

Part of those symbols name (i.e. `_TtC8sharingd19SDAirDropHandlerIPA` or `canHandleTransfer`) are present in the string table of the mach-o file.

However, they're present as different strings.

### 2.

The symbol `<redacted function xxx>` is not present anywhere in the mach-o file.

### 3.

Theses symbols are not references by the `LC_SYMTABS` load command.

Answer (score 0):

I also reproduced the `nm` command and I also did not handle this case. Thank you for sharing.

Looking at the [LLVM source code](https://gitlab.kitware.com/third-party/llvm/blob/6a7f25d30d648d81dc5b5942788ead68617e0cb4/tools/llvm-nm/llvm-nm.cpp), it seems that:

if `nm` encounters a `LC_FUNCTION_STARTS` (function starts segment), then it will get different (function?) addresses.

It checks that each of theses addresses is already in the `symbol table`.

If it is not, then comes the case that we do not handle:

See the comment at line 1672: "See this address is not already in the table symbol fake up an nlist for it."

```
        // See this address is not already in the symbol table fake up an
        // nlist for it.
        if (!found) {
          NMSymbol F = {};
          F.Name = "<redacted function X>";
          F.Address = FoundFns[f] + BaseSegmentAddress;
          F.Size = 0;
          // There is no symbol in the nlist symbol table for this so we set
          // Sym effectivly to null and the rest of code in here must test for
          // it and not do things like Sym.getFlags() for it.
          F.Sym = BasicSymbolRef();
          F.SymFlags = 0;
          F.NType = MachO::N_SECT;
          F.NSect = 0;
          StringRef SegmentName = StringRef();
          StringRef SectionName = StringRef();
          for (const SectionRef &Section : MachO->sections()) {
            Section.getName(SectionName);
            SegmentName = MachO->getSectionFinalSegmentName(
                                                Section.getRawDataRefImpl());
            F.NSect++;
            if (F.Address >= Section.getAddress() &&
                F.Address < Section.getAddress() + Section.getSize()) {
              F.Section = Section;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (SegmentName == "__TEXT" && SectionName == "__text")
            F.TypeChar = 't';
          else if (SegmentName == "__DATA" && SectionName == "__data")
            F.TypeChar = 'd';
          else if (SegmentName == "__DATA" && SectionName == "__bss")
            F.TypeChar = 'b';
          else
            F.TypeChar = 's';
          F.NDesc = 0;
          F.IndirectName = StringRef();
          SymbolList.push_back(F);
          if (FoundFns[f] == lc_main_offset)
            FOS << "<redacted LC_MAIN>";
          else
            FOS << "<redacted function " << f << ">";
          FOS << '\0';
          FunctionStartsAdded++;
        }
```

And that's how these symbols seem to appear.